# Finder crashes when double-clicking on a file but not when opening the file through Spotlight

Tags: finder, catalina, crash

All,

I've been experiencing Finder crashes on my older iMac (27", late 2013) running Catalina (10.15.7). When I try and open a file or application through Finder by double-clicking or using the Dock, Finder crashes. If I try and do the same through Spotlight, the file or application opens.

I ran EtreCheck and looked at the log files, and it seems that more than just Finder has been crashing. So has `Spotlight`, `Dock`, `passd`, `diagnostics_agent`, `analyticsd`, and `dasd`. All crash with a similar error, a segmentation fault. I've posted an excerpt from the Finder crash log below:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000002dcaa19a4
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2510]
```

Things I've noticed and things I've tried:

- The problem seemed to start after I tried using AirPlay to connect to a Vizio TV to stream video. There was a lot of connecting and disconnecting.
- The problem is persistent. It exists from the moment of user login.
- Both user accounts are experiencing the same issue. <strike>The other user account on the machine isn't experiencing the same issue.</strike> (Edit: Before, I swear only one user account was experiencing the issue. Now it seems like both are.)
- Booting into Safe Mode didn't help. I checked to confirm I was in safe mode.
- Ran disk recovery on start up to check the hard drive (Cmd-R). It found no issues.
- I removed the Finder plist file (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`) and rebooted
- I removed the SidebarLists plist file (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidbarlists.plist`) and rebooted

I'm not sure of where to go from here. Any suggestions? I can attach any of the crash reports or EtreCheck report if useful.

Sean

Comment: 1) Do you have any Finder extensions? If so, remove them. 2) Does problem only occur after using AirPlay with no issue between startup and AirPlay?

Comment: @Gilby 1. I don't believe I have installed any Finder extensions. 2. The problem is persistent. It exists from the moment of user login.

Comment: Thanks. Clarified things a bit.  But, sadly, I don't know how to proceed.